# React and Next.js for server-side rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new to React and have started working on a project which uses Next.js for server-side rendering. The application will also use Next.js for routing. I'm having trouble understanding at what point does the browser pull the application code from the server.

When the browser starts the application, is the entire application (in vanilla JS) pulled from the server at one time? Or are pieces of the application pulled from the server as needed as the user routes between different pages?

Comment: See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages - to summarize, part of it is built on the server, and part is generated interactively on the client

Comment: And it looks like there is at most one html pull from the server per page load